# Show posts assigned to multiple categories in current category page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have the posts assigned to each category. However, some posts need to be assigned to multiple categories and this is when the code breaks. No error message whatsoever. Whenever I assign a post to multiple categories, the Wordpress website just loads posts from Cat1 only.

My post-assignment method:

```
Post1 - Cat1
Post2 - Cat2
Post3 - Cat1,Cat3,Cat4
Post4 - Cat3
Post5 - Cat4
```

Here's my code that works if each post is assigned to one single category. Once a post is assigned to multiple category, it fails. This is the code I have on `category.php`

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
    $myposts = get_posts(
        array(
            'numberposts' => -1, 
            'offset' => 0, 
            'category__in' => array($category),
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'order'=>'ASC' 
            )
        );
    foreach($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo substr(get_the_title(),0,55); ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: My guess is `$category = $category[0]->cat_ID` is the problem. You are only ever looking at the first category.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that on a category page you want to get the queried object, the category, not the global $post object, which I think will be the post last added to the category. Try this code and see how it works.

```
$category = get_queried_object();
$cat_id = $category->term_id;

$myposts = get_posts(
    array(
        'numberposts' => -1, 
        'offset' => 0, 
        'category' => $cat_id,
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'order'=>'ASC' 
        )
    );
```